# How to convert a two nested list of lists into a nested list of tuples in Python?

Tags: python, type-conversion, tuples, nested-lists

I am trying to convert a **two** nested list of lists into a nested list of tuples in Python. But I cant get the desired result.
The **input** looks like:

```
first_list = [['best', 'show', 'ever', '!'],
              ['its', 'a', 'great', 'action','movie']]

second_list = [['O', 'B_A', 'O', 'O'],
               ['O', 'O', 'O', 'B_A','I_A']]
```

The desired **output** should look like:

```
result = [[('best','O'),('show','B_A'),('ever','O'),('!','O')],
          [('its','O'),('a','O'),('great','O'),('action','B_A'),('movie','I_A')]]
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# zip both lists. You end up with pairs of lists
pl = zip(first_list, second_list)

# zip each pair of list and make list of tuples out of each pair of lists.
[[(e[0], e[1]) for e in zip(l[0], l[1])] for l in pl]
```

Note: not tested, done on mobile. But you got the idea.

Comment: It's still missing a bracket that's why I added one after e[1], it works now! thank you!